# Facebook like box won't work with Facebook connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have both like box and connect on the same page and I am trying to get the html5 or xfbml code of the like box to work with Facebook connect but it won't. Only the iframe code will work but the thing is I can't customize anything in iframe. Any advice?

Comment: Can you link to a live example or paste your code?

Comment: Hey Abby, thanks for the request. You can see my page source here - triumphpoint.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you got:

xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"

In your html open tag at the top of you page?

Comment: Are you using the Facebook JS SDK and do you have any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: Yes Ben and the error I got is FB.Type.createClass2 is not a function on XFBML (line 16).

Comment: I suggest you take all the other javascript files off the page, and see if you can get it to work without them, then put them back one at a time.